# Is Discord mobile app really built with react native?

Tags: react-native

In the show case https://facebook.github.io/react-native/showcase.html it shows Discord. Is it really built with react native? I couldn't find any blog/article on this.

The app looks too nice to be built with react native.

Comment: I'm interested on this too... Searched a lot in some other places, but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: This is not an opinion site

Comment: Whether or not the app is built with react native or not is a fact, not an opinion.  This is a legit question imo.  When looking at potential new tools for xplat mobile development people want to see what the tools have been used for in the wild.  I wish I could +1 this question again.

Comment: Overzealous moderators at it again

Answer (score 7):

I actually found the answer myself, see react newsletter here:
http://brentvatne.ca/react-native-newsletter/07-09-2015.html

> "Discord is the only cross-platform voice and text chat app designed specifically for gamers. With the iOS companion app you can stay connected to all your Discord voice and text channels even while AFK. It is perfect for chatting with team members, seeing who is playing online, and catching up on text conversations you may have missed."
>
> The actual chat view drops down to native (well, React-Inspired ComponentKit) because the team couldn't get the performance that they needed out of ListView, but the rest is React Native! Beautiful work."

Answer (score 6):

Well, this might not be a completely well formed answer, but they tweeted that yes, they use react native on IOS.

https://twitter.com/discordapp/status/641815156838666240

:)

Answer (score 4):

The Discord iOS app is written in React Native but their Android app is not. From a [blog post on 2018-07-26](https://blog.discordapp.com/why-discord-is-sticking-with-react-native-ccc34be0d427):

> Similar to iOS, we tried React Native the day it was released for Android. We were surprised by how easily and quickly we were able to make our comprehensive iOS app run on Android — took only two days and it built!
>
> However, we immediately stopped after identifying various issues such as poor performance of touch events and lack of 64-bit support. We continued to follow React Native Android through observing many other apps and blog posts, but there have been no fundamental improvements to convince us to try again.

Comment: This is no longer the case, now their Android app is also built using react native: https://discord.com/blog/android-react-native-framework-update